# Carbon integrated seatpost small dent

Tags: carbon, seatpost

I have a Ridley Noah frame that has a really small dent in the integrated seatpost, the dent itself does not seem to be caused by an object hitting it. It looks like it has been caused by hanging it on a bike stand with the clamp attached to the seat post.

It is hard to describe the damage. It looks like the frame slide down while hanging in the clamp. You can see a small layer of carbon being exposed above and below the dent, the dent itself has two layers of carbon visible. The dent can be best described as if it was sanded down.

In the picture below you can see the dent on the lefthand side of the seatpost, in the centre of the picture

[image]

I did not notice this until today. I have ridden quite a lot of miles since I got it back from a bike mechanic. My guess is the damage occurred while in maintenance.

Can such a dent, not caused by the frame being hit by something, compromise the strength of the seat tube? I can take the frame to a carbon repair shop if needed.

Comment: Looks like a clamping incident. Take it back to THAT mechanic.

Comment: @Carel Already did that, he denies it...

Comment: @Odyssee mechanic-error damages are really tough to settle when there is no proof or documentation. I guess you'll just have to bite your saddle and take it to a carbon repair shop.

for future contingency, you can perform an pre-maintenance M check together with the assigned mechanic, list (on 2 copies) any scratches, damages, and the components on the bike, and have the mechanic and yourself sign each.

I'd do it if my bike is precious or expensive enough.
OR you can maintain your bike yourself. :)

Comment: I have found maintaining it myself these kinds of things make me madder, but I get over it quicker :)